# Most efficient way of triggering DoesNotExist Exception for pk

Tags: django, django-models

I want to see if an id exists in the db without getting the instance from the db. And I want to trigger a DoesNotExist exception if it does not exist. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
   MyModel.objects.get(pk=my_model_id)
```

but is there a more efficient but clear alternative?

Also, for a call to an endpoint, it is common to return a 404 if the id of the resource is not found in the db. This can be achieved by adding an error handler that catches all DoesNotExist exceptions and returns a 404 with the exception message. But it is also common to only require one field from the model instance.

So its like this is the efficient way:

```
if not MyModel.objects.exists(pk=my_model_id):
    raise DoesNotExist()

item = MyModel.objects.filter(pk=my_model_id).values_list("item", flat=True)[0]
```

But I do this instead because the above code is way too verbose and unclear:

```
item = MyModel.objects.get(pk=my_model_id).item
```

Comment: The most efficient would be to use [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) Returns only a boolean but does not raise an `ObjectDoesNotExist`. The docs also mention the following: "This tries to perform the query in the simplest and fastest way possible, but it does execute nearly the same query as a normal QuerySet query."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient would be to use [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists). It returns only a boolean but does not raise an ObjectDoesNotExist. The docs also mention:

> This tries to perform the query in the simplest and fastest way
> possible, but it does execute nearly the same query as a normal QuerySet query.

If you need only one or a few fields I recommend you to make a normal query. This should satisfy all your requirements.

```
MyModel.objects.values("item").get(pk=my_model_id)
```

This produces the following clean and simple SQL statement:

```
SELECT "item" FROM "my_model" WHERE "pk"."id" = my_model_id...
```

This will also raise a `MyModel.DoesNotExist` if no object can be found.